# Cannot load DataTable with OdbcDataReader

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a query running over ODBC for a C-Tree database which looks like this:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(TO_CHAR(first_visit_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD '), 
TO_CHAR('00:00:00', 'HH24')) AS date_first_visit FROM admin.v_patient
```

Which returns results like this:

```
1, 2015-03-07 00:00:00  
2, 2016-01-27 00:00:00
```

Of course the full query is much larger, but this is the only field giving me trouble. When I try loading the data using this:

```
using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand(cmdText, conn))
    {
        using (OdbcDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var rawData = new DataTable();
            rawData.Load(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.ConstraintException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.
```

I have tried updating my query to be

```
SELECT id, '2015-03-07 00:00:00 ' AS date_first_visit 
FROM admin.v_patient
```

which works... It should be the exact same thing, except now every row has the same date. For grins I tried converting that to varchar using this:

```
CONVERT('VARCHAR', TO_CHAR(first_visit_date, \'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00\') )
```

and other ways, but the real trouble seems to be loading the DataTable, but I can't figure out what the difference would be between the results from the query, or the one in my example where I just specify a string.

I haven't defined any constraints on the table, which seems to wipe out the errors of `non-null, or foreign-key constraints`, and since I can reuse the same date in every row, that seems to wipe out `unique`, which leaves me wondering what the heck is wrong.

Comment: Why are you using a DataTable? Why don't you just create a class that has properties that represent the data? They tend to be much easier to work with than a DataTable.

Comment: I think you get multiple rows per id so your "first visit" logic is wrong, its not a problem with the date.

Comment: @mason I am using my connector as a generic method that handles a variety of queries. The only thing it needs to do is load a datatable to be converted to JSON using Newtonsoft.Json, as such defining classes would be overkill.

Comment: @Crowcoder I am not sure how I would get multiple results on the same row here, This method is working for other queries with thousands of results, and this query that has 20 columns works great as long as I eliminate the ones with dates

Comment: Did you ORDER BY id or group by count(id) in the "other queries"? With that many rows you may not see the duplicates.

Comment: I was able to verify there are no duplicate records, but oddly I can load them if I do it one at a time by specifying the id.

Comment: OK, so found the issue is that any row that has multiple null values fails. I have multiple fields such as first_name, last_name, birthdate, address, city... So if I have a row where the address and city are blank, I can't load it??? Any way to overcome such a limitation?

Comment: Do you have any constraints on the columns with null values?

Comment: Not that I specified, maybe there are some defaults screwing me up. I solved it with the code below.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the `rawData.Load(reader)` with this code fixes the issue:

```
DataTable dtSchema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
List<DataColumn> listCols = new List<DataColumn>();
var rawData = new DataTable();
if (dtSchema != null)
{
    foreach (DataRow drow in dtSchema.Rows)
    {
        string columnName = System.Convert.ToString(drow["ColumnName"]);
        DataColumn column = new DataColumn(columnName, (Type)(drow["DataType"]));
        column.Unique = false;
        column.AllowDBNull = true;
        column.AutoIncrement = false;

        listCols.Add(column);
        rawData.Columns.Add(column);
    }
}
while (reader.Read())
{
    DataRow dataRow = rawData.NewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < listCols.Count; i++)
    {
        dataRow[((DataColumn)listCols[i])] = reader[i];
    }
    rawData.Rows.Add(dataRow);
}
```