# Loading Datatable using odbcdatareading in postgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql

I am writing a **generic** method to accept a mixture of odbccommands for my postgresql database. In the code sample below I am using a odbcdatareader to get the data and place the reader into a datatable and return that datatable. However the datatable is always empty when I debug my code. Not sure why. Any help is appreciated. (I saw this link here: [Cannot load DataTable with OdbcDataReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48430387/cannot-load-datatable-with-odbcdatareader) but it wasn't much help)

```
    public DataTable Query(OdbcCommand command)
    {
        var rawData = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                connection.Open();

                // Execute the DataReader and access the data.
                using (OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    rawData.Load(reader);
                }



                // Call Close when done reading.
                //reader.Close();          
            }

            return rawData;
        }
        catch (OdbcException e)
        {
            logger.Log(e, EventLogEntryType.Warning);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked, that sql you are sending is actually returning any data? Simple thing should be addressed first?:)

Comment: @fatherOfWine when I debug my postgresql command does return data to the "reader" but rawData is empty when it is returned. Which confuses me.

Comment: That's odd, I would agree. If reader has the data dtataTable should has it as well. At this point I would suggest to use OdbcDataAdapter.Fill() along with DataSet maybe that will make adifferencee.
Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @fatherOfWine I found the issue. During a debug session I found that I was using the wrong column name when looping through the datatable after it was returned. So when making postgresql commands and retrieve data from datatables the heading names are super important. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yep, column names are important.:) Glad you able to resolve the issue.